# How can you separate sub atomic particles and manipulate them?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, large-hadron-collider, protons

Say, in Large Hadron Collider how can people separate a proton from an atom and then accelerate it and what is even more miraculous to collide it with another proton? It sound like impossible. Especially when you consider a particle to be a wave and a particle.

Comment: I would think of particles, not waves, you can read more at : https://home.cern/topics/large-hadron-collider.  The proton is treated as a composite particle.